# Georeferencer QGIS not working?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, wgs84, png

I am trying to georeference a .png file. After inserting all the data I get the following error

"Transform Failed: Failed to compute GCP transform: Transform is not solvable."

What can be the problem?

[image]

[image]

> gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 324.814 728.712 11.3582 43.5428 -gcp
> 354.101 637.672 11.3582 45.5428 -gcp 476.351 216.605 11.3586 43.5427 -gcp 518.207 168.548 11.3585 43.5426 -gcp 342.315 362.074 11.3585 43.5428 "C:/Giulio_files/Documenti/University/PhD/PhD Thesis/Data/02_Aerial photos/frattaglie.png"
> "C:/Users/Giulio/AppData/Local/Temp/frattaglie.png"
>
> gdalwarp -r near
> -tps -co COMPRESS=NONE  "C:/Users/Giulio/AppData/Local/Temp/frattaglie.png"
> "C:/Giulio_files/Documenti/University/PhD/PhD Thesis/Data/02_Aerial
> photos/frattaglie_modified.tif"

Comment: the transform is not solvable! - please add in a screen shot showing your map and the control points on the image and the map

Comment: Something is wrong with the ground control points which you have introduced. You should see also the gdalwarp and gdal_translate commands which the tool is generating, copy-paste them into your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks to both, I added the screenshot and the command

Comment: If you set CRS to EPSG:32632 you must give the coordinates of GCP's in the same system. You seem to have EPSG:4326 GCP's now. But you must have also something else wrong. I must be thinking a little bit.

Comment: possibly related to [this issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12795)? (it mentions jpg, but may be the same thing - saving your TIFF with a PNG extentsion causing gdalwarp to fail in the second step)

Comment: Even with nospaces, changing EPSG and with a tiff image it didn't work

Comment: `gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 324.814 728.712 11.3582 43.5428 -gcp 354.101 637.672 11.3582 45.5428 -gcp 339.426 362.305 11.3585 45.5428 -gcp 476.351 216.605 11.3586 43.5427 -gcp 518.207 168.548 11.3585 43.5426 "C:/Giulio_files/Documenti/University/PhD/PhD_Thesis/Data/02_Aerial_photos/frattaglie.tif" "C:/Users/Giulio/AppData/Local/Temp/frattaglie.tif"
gdalwarp -r near -tps -co COMPRESS=NONE  "C:/Users/Giulio/AppData/Local/Temp/frattaglie.tif" "C:/Giulio_files/Documenti/University/PhD/PhD_Thesis/Data/02_Aerial_photos/frattaglie_modified.tif"
`

Comment: You could try to georeference in a different software, like ArcMap or Blue Marble. They both have trial options. Also a conversion of the image to a different format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the ground control points in the generated gdalwarp command you should see that they do not make sense.

```
     pixel   row     x        y 
-gcp 324.814 728.712 11.3582 43.5428 
-gcp 354.101 637.672 11.3582 45.5428 
-gcp 476.351 216.605 11.3586 43.5427 
-gcp 518.207 168.548 11.3585 43.5426 
-gcp 342.315 362.074 11.3585 43.5428
```

Two of the points have exactly same coordinates but still different pixel/row. Three other points have almost identical coordinates.

The reason may be that QGIS is automatically truncating coordinates at fourth place which is too coarse for you. As a workaround measure your Ground Control points in EPSG:32632 units or measure as EPSG:4326 but convert to EPSG:32632 for QGIS. You can do that with gdaltransform http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html.

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:32632
11.3582 43.5428
690515.193804498 4823796.38860415 0
```

Alternatively, if you have accurate EPSG:4326 coordinates you can edit the gdal_translate command by hand and run gdal_translate directly from the command shell.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be a problem with out output destination C:/Giulio_files/Documenti/University/PhD/PhD Thesis/Data/02_Aerial photos

try changing PhD Thesis to PhD_Thesis - I've had problems with spaces in destination folder paths in the past

Comment: Done, but it didin't solve